# Environment tag helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm working with Visual Studio 15 RC, and I noticed in the _Layout.cshtml, there is a new `environment` tag helper:

```
   <environment names="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="hidden" asp-fallback-test-property="visibility" asp-fallback-test-value="hidden" />
    </environment>
```

How would I indicate that that I want a `Staging` build to get the CSS files from the CDN?

Comment: CSS will always be get from the CDN. Local css files are used as fallback when CDN failed. Maybe I don't understand what you mean by your question.

Comment: No, if this was a development deployment, the CSS would be served locally. I'm unclear how I indicate the deployment is Development, Staging, or Production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to specify **Staging** environment for your build :

- Open your project properties
- Select the **Debug** tab
- In the **Environment variables** section, if a variable named **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** doesn't exist then add it by clicking to the **add** button. After that set the value of the variable to **Staging** by double-clicking in the cell.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes here,

If the framework you are targeting is **ASP.NET Core** then,
Environment variable name should be **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT**.
Check this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/144#issuecomment-195539322) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your environment in launchsetting.json file which you can find in your solution under properties